# How can I display text files with alternating background highlights on each line?

Tags: windows, formatting, report, text-editor, user-experience

My application generates reports to a Winows text file (.txt), and I would like to automatically highlight alternate rows when users open the file. The text files are currently being opened with Notepad.

Answer (score -1):

I think you would be better served by outputting your report in a different format, and instructing your users to view it in a different program, such as an HTML file viewed in a web browser.  I think that neither the .txt format nor the Notepad application support text highlighting.

UPDATE: If it is a requirement that you keep the .txt format, but can use a different application, here is another option.

If you import your text file into the Google Sheets spreadsheet application, it will put each line of text in the first cell of a single row (so if your file is 10 lines long, your spreadsheet will have 10 rows).  You can then use the "Format -> Alternating colors" option to apply different colors to alternating lines.

Comment: I cannot output to html. I need an alternative to Notepad that is able to provide the desired formatting.

Comment: The issue is not just the editor, but the output format as well.  A plain text file does not support the kind of formatting you're looking for.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this answer: please leave a comment letting me know what the problem is, so that I can improve future answers.

Comment: Plain text file may not support formatting, but a tool used for displaying the text could provide it.